# When someone changes their mind in doing something

Tags: word-usage, word-request

I wonder what word do you usually use in the following contexts:

> **Scenario 1:** 
>   I was a student of art at the university of X. Two years ago, when I was a junior student, I changed my mind and .............. from continuing study at that university. (how a student announces to the university that they want to quit the university and subsequently their major? What verb is used here? What is such a student doing in this case?)
>
> **Scenario 2:** 
>   Let's suppose that someone is going to purchase a house and due to some reasons .............. (what single word is used here when they change their mind and stop buying the house?)

I know some words that seem to be able to be used in both of the sentences above, but I have no idea that grammatically and semantically it is possible or not! Words like: **"[dissuade](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/dissuade)" - "[resign](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/english/resign)" - "[give up](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.macmillandictionary.com/amp/dictionary/british/give-up)"**

As I know and dictionaries say, **dissuade** means:

> -To persuade someone not to do something:

— I tried to dissuade her from leaving.

But perhaps it is not possible to use this verb in a passive sentence (in my examples.)

Also, I have seen in many occasions in which the words **"resign"** and **"give up"** were used in some similar cases, but still I don't know what would you use here in my examples in natural English.

Answer (score 1):

"Abandon" is a useful word that you could use here

> I abandoned my studies
>
> I abandoned the hunt for a new house.

You can drop out:

> I dropped out of university after the first year
>
> I dropped out of the housing market.

Slightly more active is "pulled out"

> I pulled out from the house purchase at the last moment when the interest rate rose.

Or you can rephrase to say what you are doing instead:

> I changed my mind and started a business
>
> due to some reasons I decided to move back in with my parents.